# MySQL Replication Thousands of Writes Per Second

Tags: mysql, database

For my application I need my database to handle say 1000 updates per second at peak time, this isn't too much of a problem I just need the right server. However, if this server goes down I need a backup with the synced data to take over. How do I sync the data to another database?

In a separate part of my application I have a master and a slave, the slave replicates the master and the slave is read only. Could I use this method for my problem? I have looked into mysql clusters but so far reading about clusters is just making me more confused.

So put simply, how can I replicate my database handing 1000 writes per second, in case of downtime?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions one simple but requiring manual reconfiguration in the event of the main server going down, the other more complex but more robust.

A) Simple replication - you can configure a slave server that receives updates from the master server. Both servers must be able to handle the number of updates and queries that you foresee. In the event of the master server failing, you need to manually swap the slave into the master role. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

B) Clustering - I'm not very familiar with MySQL clustering, but it gives synchronous updates to all servers and automatic failover  - http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/